# How to route between pages with minimum re-render in a dashboard in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The Dashboard looks something like this:

```
export default function Dashboard({ children }) {
return (
    <>
        <DashboardLayout menu={menu}>
            <DashboardPage variant="cards" flow="one-one">
                {children}
            </DashboardPage>
        </DashboardLayout>
    </>
)
```

}

The Dashboard has a sidebar menu on the left which allows for navigating between different DashboardPages. Because the Dashboard pages all share components like the `menu`, the `sidebar`, the `footer`, etc., I ideally don't want to re-render these components.

If I use the Next.JS native `<Link>` component, then the all components get re-rendered.

The only alternative I see to this is using a React hook like `useState` or `useReducer` to set which pages gets rendered as such:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer();

return (
    <>
        <DashboardLayout menu={menu}>
            <DashboardPage variant="cards" flow="one-one">
                {state == 'page1' && <DashboardPage1 />}
                {state == 'page2' && <DashboardPage1 />}
                {state == 'page3' && <DashboardPage1 />}
                ...
                {state == 'pageN' && <DashboardPageN />}
            </DashboardPage>
        </DashboardLayout>
    </>
)
```

}

Is there a way to use routing such as  or the useRoute hook and avoid re-rendering certain components? For example, whenever I change between dashboard pages, I see that a console log inside the "DashboardLayout", which does not need to re-render, gets printed 4 times.

Comment: React generally rerenders when it needs to. Are you seeing an actual performance degradation, i.e. have you actively measured/audited the performance? How exactly are you validating/verifying what is rendered/rerendered? Can you [edit] the post to share more relevant details and more specifically what the issue is?

Comment: @DrewReese just edited the post. I do the validations checking Network in chrome developer tools and with simple console logs inside the components. The performance is not degraded severely, but it does take long for pages to render sometimes. Mostly I want to understand if shared components are expected to re-render when navigating or if there is a better way to handle navigation to minimise what gets loaded.

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to show *exactly* how you are checking rerenders? Specifically I am asking if you are console logging in the `useEffect` hook which is called exactly once per render, or if you are logging somewhere else as an unintentional side-effect. Seeing a more complete [mcve] may also help us better understand what the code is doing and how a user interacts with the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in  tag of NextJS and NextJS Router

```
{/* Adding the Link Component */}
<Link href="/"> Dashboard</Link>
```

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push('/dashboard')}>
      Dashboard
    </button>
  );
}
```

Or you can use React-Router-DOM for navigation using useNavigate hook
An eg. of React-router

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Page = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => navigate('/pagename')}>
      Go To Page
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, there is still the question of "minimum re-rendering". If I route as you propose here, if I am not mistaken, this would have the same effect as using a `<Link>` component, wouldn't it? Which means that things like the sidebar, menu and footer would re-render? I might be wrong here, but just want to make sure :)